# Track iOS & Android App Downloads

Tags: ios, google-play

We had published an app in iOS & Android store last year. When I go to the google play store I can see 50,000 to 100,000 App downloads. But how can I know how much exact number of apps are downloaded. Kindly can somebody help me how to check.

Please note I have username & password for both iOS & Android developers account.

Comment: You can able to see in your developer console login

Comment: But in which area of developer console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Play downloads, you can view it at [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) > Current / Total Installs.

For iOS downloads, you can view it at [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) > Sales and Trends.